# Какие параметры нужно использовать в prop= для получения всего текста?

Tags: php, mediawiki, mediawiki-api

Какие параметры нужно использовать в prop= для получения всего текста?
`prop=info` дает короткий текст.
Также необходимо получать главную картинку из статьи, если есть, ее url, как это сделать?
А еще, если в api есть такие возможности, нужны ссылки на другие статьи, которые есть внутри исходной.

Если кто-то подскажет с параметрами, буду благодарен.

Answer (score 1):

По мне, так легче парсить страницу, `API mediawiki` движка была создана немного для других целей, она сырая и малопригодная. Парси страницу, все необходимые тебе элементы в одном дизайне и оформлении, а это главное.